# Existe alguma maneira de alterar uma coluna de uma tabela existente para "auto increment"?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Criei uma tabela em Sqlite3, porém esqueci de adicionar `AUTO INCREMENT` na coluna `id`.

Tentei usar `ALTER TABLE` para resolver o problema, mas ainda não consegui.

Em SQLITE, é permitido definir uma coluna como *auto increment*, depois de a tabela já ter sido criada?

Se não tiver, qual é a solução para tornar meu campo `id` como *auto increment*?

Meu esquema atualmente é:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER, name STRING);
```

Comment: Wallace vê se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631060/can-i-alter-a-column-in-an-sqlite-table-to-autoincrement-after-creation

Comment: Não manjo muito de linha de comando. As vezes apelo pra esse aplicativo: http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: @Zooboomafoo a dica é boa, vou dar uma olhada sim. Até então, eu sempre mexia no SQLITE via linha de comando.

Answer (score 2):

Para criar um campo com auto incremento, primeiramente é necessário que o tipo de dado da coluna seja INTEGER.

Veja o comando abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE [tabela] (
 [ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);
```

Para alterar um campo para um outro tipo no sqlite, pelo que pesquisei não é possível usando um comando alter table >> alter column, seria necessário fazer um malabarismo criando uma tabela de backup, depois recriando a tabela principal, depois repopulando a tabela principal com os dados que foram gravados na tabela de backup.

Ou se preferir, você pode usar uma ferramenta visual para fazer a mudança do campo ID para AutoIncrement.

Eu utilizo a ferramenta SQLite Expert Personal 4.x e ela faz isso maravilhosamente bem.

Download: http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html